# Проблема с добавлением горячих клавиш keyboard

Tags: python, pyqt5, клавиатура, binding

Делаю приложение на PyQt, пытаюсь сделать установку горячих клавиш.
Клавиши подгружаются из базы данных при запуске.

Проблема:
При запуске приложения сразу выполняются действия горячих клавиш, а при последующем их нажатии
вылезает ошибка.

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ashig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ashig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ashig\Documents\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_generic.py", line 58, in process
    if self.pre_process_event(event):
  File "C:\Users\ashig\Documents\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 218, in pre_process_event
    callback(event)
  File "C:\Users\ashig\Documents\project\venv\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 649, in <lambda>
    handler = lambda e: (event_type == KEY_DOWN and e.event_type == KEY_UP and e.scan_code in _logically_pressed_keys) or (event_type == e.event_type and callback())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Код:

```
import keyboard
import sqlite3
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication,
                             QMainWindow)
from design.py.macros import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.add_combination()

    def add_combination(self):
        con = sqlite3.connect('macros_db.sqlite')
        cur = con.cursor()

        data = cur.execute("""SELECT combination, url_file FROM macros""").fetchall()
        for hotkey, url in data:
            keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, os.startfile(url))

        con.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предположить, что тут `lambda` поможет сделать отложенное выполнение, которое вы хотели:

```
keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, lambda x=url: os.startfile(x))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло